# Need help trying to reset cum sum value back to zero when criteria is not meet by comparing values in previous rows from another column

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I am trying to put a 1 or Yes if Price Increase twice in a row. I tried using cumsum, but I can't figure out how to reset the value back to zero if it isn't true

```
df["Increased Twice?"] = ((df.shift(1)["Price Change"] == df3bet["Price Change"])).cumsum()
```

This the result from the code I have

```
ProductID  Price Change  Increased Twice?
 2d3Q       Increase            0
 2d3Q       Increase            1
 2d3Q       Decrease            1
 2d3Q       Increase            1
 2d3Q       Increase            2
 2d3Q       Decrease            2
 2d3Q       Increase            2
 2d3Q       Increase            3
```

This is what I want

```
ProductID  Price Change  Increased Twice?
 2d3Q       Increase            0
 2d3Q       Increase            1
 2d3Q       Decrease            0
 2d3Q       Increase            0
 2d3Q       Increase            1
 2d3Q       Decrease            0
 2d3Q       Increase            0
 2d3Q       Increase            1
```

I have also tried some different if then statements, but I haven't it gotten to work.

Comment: What is the expected output in case of three consecutive _Increase_?

Comment: That would be two or maybe have a three value since that would make more logical sense.

Comment: Looks like your code already works if you remove the cumsum. But here is a better solution:  `df['Price Change'].eq('Increase') & df['Price Change'].shift().eq('Increase'))` Beware your code will fail if you have 2 or more consecutive "Decrease" as well.

Comment: yeah it worked after i took out the cumsum.

Comment: @cs95 This works well as it avoids Decrease repetition, something I  think the accepted answer fails at?

Comment: Thanks I will try this as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `numpy.where()`:

```
import numpy as np

df['Increased Twice?'] = np.where(df['Price Change'] == df.shift(1)['Price Change'], 1, 0)
```

Comment: This is similar to what i had, but without numpy. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Let's try, first find where 'Increase' then create groups based on 'Decrease', then sum and check for count of 2 increases.

```
df['Increased Twice?'] = ((df['Price Change'] == 'Increase')\
                          .groupby((df['Price Change'] == 'Decrease').cumsum())\
                          .cumsum() == 2).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
  ProductID Price Change  Increased Twice?
0      2d3Q     Increase                 0
1      2d3Q     Increase                 1
2      2d3Q     Decrease                 0
3      2d3Q     Increase                 0
4      2d3Q     Increase                 1
5      2d3Q     Decrease                 0
6      2d3Q     Increase                 0
7      2d3Q     Increase                 1
```